# Find eccentricity of a "weird" ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Let the ellipse $x^2+2y^2+2xy=1$ Find the eccentricity of this ellipse

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: on a side note, there is a general formula for eccentricity for any 2 degree curve available on Math.S.E.

Comment: There is a formula for the eccentricity [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#Values). If this is not the kind of solution you want, then it would help if you explained how you are meant to solve the problem. If this is from a class, then how have similar problems been solved?

Comment: @BenGrossmann If i had encountered the question by the OP, it would have been https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7243bc5d4717aaf1723f4046ea15c1f83a943b32 because this ellipse is rotated, same wiki page, under the heading *Eccentricity in terms of coefficients*

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775650/coordinates-of-focus-of-parabola/3775661#3775661

Comment: This isnt from class, this is a part of an excercise from calculus

Comment: Can you rotate the ellipse, to put it into standard form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+2y^2+2xy=1$$
Let $x=r \cos t, y= r\sin t$, then
$$r^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2 t+ 2\sin^2 t+\sin 2t}= \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 t+\sin 2t}=\frac{2}{2+1-\cos 2t+\sin 2t}$$
$$\implies r^2=\frac{2}{3-\sqrt{2}(\sin (t-\pi/4)}$$
So $$r_{min}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{2}}}. r_{max}==\sqrt{\frac{2}{3-\sqrt{2}}}$$
So the eccentricity $$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{r_{min}^2}{r_{max}^2}}$$ $$=\sqrt{1-\frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{3+\sqrt{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3+\sqrt{2}}}=0.8004...$$